# Getting Exception : org.hibernate.exception.sqlgrammarexception

Tags: java, hibernate

Hi I am implementing `hibernate`, When I am trying to insert a new record getting the Exception `org.hibernate.exception.sqlgrammarexception`

My `hibernate.cfg.xml` file :

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate_db</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">system</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <mapping class="com.hib.UserDetails"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

If I changed the

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
            <mapping class="com.hib.UserDetails"/>
```

It worked, But I have to create table manually.
What might be the issue?

Comment: My advice would be don't specifically choose a dialect, unless you're 100% sure you're choosing the right one. Hibernate is very good at determining what type of database it's connecting to. If you want more help, you'll need to post code where the exception is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the piece of code where you are throwing your SQL/HQL query.
There you may find some simple yet hard to find mistakes like wrongly spelt commands,etc.
That's why sql 'grammar' exception

Answer (score 0):

Check mapping class "UserDeatails".

There is mismatch between manually created table and UserDetails mapping class.

Possibly mismatch Column_Names, Id, Constraints ..etc

Answer (score 0):

check for column names in table and match with column names in @column annotation in bean. Most probably its column mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the Stacktrace of the Exception, also it would be of help if you could post the code which is adding the User to Database.
It can either be a problem with the Column names of Database table and the declared variables.

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
```

These must be generating the SQL Statement, check if there is an error in the Generated SQL Statement. Posting the SQL could also help.